Select a row in a pandas dataframe where any cell in multiple columns are not null
I have a pandas dataframe that contains multiple columns, some of which have cells with no data in there. I want to select all the rows where at least one of these columns contains some data.
Original data frame looks like this:
Time,name,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
12:01:30,James,22,34,,25
12:30:23,Dave,,,,
12:34:00,Mark,,34,,
13:02:23,Helen,34,23,12,76
13:20:43,Harry,,,,
132:35:20,Sally,,34,,

Final output should look like this:
Time,name,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
12:01:30,James,22,34,,25
12:34:00,Mark,,34,,
13:02:23,Helen,34,23,12,76
132:35:20,Sally,,34,,

I’m only interested in the contents of columns Col1 – Col4. The rows for Dave and Harry should be filtered out because none of columns (Col1 – Col4) contain any data. The rows for Mark and Sally are included as they have at least one cell with a value.
I have tried:
df = df[df['Col1'].notnull() & df['Col2'].notnull() & df['Col3'].notnull() & df['Col4'].notnull()]

But this gives me the one row where all cells have data in i.e. Helen. This is not what I need.
I also tried:
df = df[df['Col1'].notnull() or df['Col2'].notnull() or df['Col3'].notnull() or df['Col4'].notnull()]

But I get a message saying:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Any suggestions?

You can't use or with vectors. you would need |. But ehre you should use .dropna(subset=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'], how='all')
